# Content query webpart using dynamic value and concatenation for QueryOverride or FilterValue1

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

We're trying to customize a Content query web-part to use dynamic data (page Id) and a concatenated character (; or |) to populate the query.

I've tried writing a `QueryOverride` like this, but not surprisingly the dynamic element doesn't work in the CAML query:

```
<![CDATA[
    <Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="RelatedDocId" />
            <Value Type="Text">[PageFieldValue:Document ID Value]</Value>
        </Contains>
     </Where>]]>
```

I've also tried to concatenate the character on the end of the `FilterValue1` value, but it's ignored or returns nothing depending on its position.

```
<property name="FilterValue1" type="string">[PageFieldValue:ae3e2a36-125d-45d3-9051-744b513536a6:_dlc_DocId:Text]|</property>
```

I don't think there's a way to set the `QueryOverride` value of the web-part with JavaScript, which would make things easier.